# php documentation get_result ambiguity

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a simple question that I'm wondering about. I was reading through the php documentation on page http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php regarding the get_result() function.

It says:

> Returns a resultset for successful SELECT queries, or FALSE for other DML queries or on failure. The mysqli_errno() function can be used to distinguish between the two types of failure.

What is confusing for me is, if the select statement returns an empty set, will it return a FALSE too? Or a TRUE result with a null set?

Thank You for your time...

Comment: A SELECT that returns an empty record set is still valid resultset, just an empty one, it is __not__ a failure

Comment: Hmm, ok. Error handling in my code puts me in the false area. Maybe some coding mistake. Thanks for the quick answer.